# Form submit to another page and then review or write to a file

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a script that users can submit certain data, and after a submit they can "review" the output and go back to previous page or submit to it again and there is my proble, the submitted page: How can I submit it again to write it to a file?

form.html

```
<form method="post" action="vaihe2.php">
<input name="laskuttaja" type="text" value="Nimi" size="25">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Lähetä" />
</form>
```

vaihe2.php

```
<?
$laskuttaja  = $_POST['laskuttaja'];

$data = '<B>'.$laskuttaja.'</b>';

echo $data;

?>
```

So how can I post that $data to next page(vaihe3.php) with submit and let the script write it to a file. I know how php write file works but the post to third page is not working.

Comment: is there a reason why you wouldn't do it on vaihe2?

Comment: You can use https://php.net/curl to achieve this.

Comment: ...or you could use `include('vaihe2.php')` in vaihe3.php...

Comment: @webeno, include works if you access vaihe3.php, but if you don't want to access it, say user enters form.html into browser, form will make vaihe2.php work, but not vaihe3.php

Comment: @CrazySabbath I meant that with `action="vaihe3.php"` actually on `form.html`, sorry, forgot to add.

Comment: Yes. But if the user sees the mistake in vaihe2 then he can go back to form.html and then correct it and then submit again to vaihe2 and then confirm it and submit to vaihe3

Answer (score 1):

In vaihe2.php

```
<form method="post" action="vaihe3.php">
    <?
    $laskuttaja  = $_POST['laskuttaja'];
    $data = '<B>'.$laskuttaja.'</b>';
    echo $data;
    echo "<input name=\"laskuttaja\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$laskuttaja."\" size=\"25\">";
    ?>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="anything" />
</form>
```

Here you are passing laskuttaja as hidden field and on post will be available to you in third page.

Now data flow as per your requirement. **User fills data in form.html -> reviews on vaihe2 and confirms -> gets written in vaihe3.**

Comment: `$laskuttaja` will be empty if the OP does it this way, nonetheless the OP might want to pass data into the field, so why would you hide it...?

Comment: In form.html user will fill in text box, on vaihe2.php (hidden parameter will contain data for you and user will see in bold as you are doing it) user will review and submit, but in vaihe3 you will store it in file.

Comment: the OP didn't speak about wanting the user to interact with vaihe2.php basically resulting in a second click, so this is no anwer to the question

Comment: OK, I understood question that way, also what is OP?

Comment: OP = Original Poster (see: [Urban Dictionary: op](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op)) - basically referring to the person who asked the question.

Comment: actually, you are correct, sorry about that! pls edit your answer a little bit, I would like to upvote your answer but cannot do it without you editing first...

Comment: I tryed hidden field but because that $laskuttaja is part of bigger script and the styling and other tags is in $data and when I do <? echo '<input type="hidden" name="laskuttaja" value="'. $data.'" ?> then the php echo will echo the full script inside the $data even when it is in hidden field. And sorry for typos, I replied from my cell phone

Comment: not `value="'. $data.'" ` but  `value="'. $laskuttaja.'"`

Comment: Yes but then I need about 50 pcs of hidden fields.

Comment: ok, then you should create an object(or any datastructure to store data) and store it in session, if user goes back and submit this session object will be updated, and if he confirms then you write it to a file. Then no hidden fields are required.

Answer (score 1):

If you wat to go back, the secret is in the value of the input.

```
<input name="laskuttaja" type="text" value="<?php echo(isset($_POST['laskuttaja'])?$_POST['laskuttaja']:"Nimi";?>" size="25"/>
```

To 'save' data to the next page use `$_SESSION`s. They're simple to use. Just remember everywhere you use them, you must have `session_start();` on LINE 1! Can't stress that enough!

```
$_SESSION['data']=$data;
```

on your third page:

```
echo$_SESSION['data'];
```

[More on sessions here.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Guess your answer posted while i was typing mine out, otherwise just would have +1 yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the form conditionally back to itself until validated by checkbox? the action would change to "vaihe3.php" ?

```
<form method="post" action="<?php if ($_POST["valid"]==1) {echo 'vaihe3.php';} ?>">
<input name="laskuttaja" type="text" value="<?php if ($_POST['laskuttaja']!=='') {echo '$_POST[laskuttaja]'} else {echo 'Nimi';} ?>" size="25">

<?php if (isset ($_POST['laskuttaja') && $_POST['laskuttaja']!=="") {
echo 'Please Confirm your answers: <input name="valid" type="checkbox" value="1" />'; } ?>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Lähetä" />
</form>
```

Otherwise, the mention above about CURL would be another option. Or - since your using PHP anyways, you could write the values of form submission to a session array and make them available to all pages until you empty the array.